# WebGL - advanced rendering with instancing

Tags: javascript, webgl, rendering

I have a library that renders models of specific formats.
These formats have animations, and constantly changing things like dynamic mesh colors (aka vertex color per mesh), meshes dynamically being visible or not, and many other things, all depending on the animations.

All was fine, and then I wanted to make the rendering actually fast and switched to instanced rendering.
Since then everything became a nightmare, and no matter how many designs I try, I simply cannot get it to work properly.

The code works in such a way that every mesh in every model owns a bucket object, which holds shared buffers for many instances of this mesh.
For example, every instance needs the mentioned dynamic vertex color, so the bucket holds one buffer with enough memory for some N vertex colors.

When a new instance is added, a free index into this buffer is given to it.
Every instance writes to this index as if it's a C pointer, and at the end the whole buffer is updated with the new values.

So far so good.

When an instance is removed, there's a hole in the buffer.
What I did was to "move" the last instance to the one that got deleted, essentially the same as changing pointers.
This isn't so nice, but it's fast.

Then the issues came in two ways - textures, and cameras.

Let's say I want one instance to use a different texture, this is impossible with instanced rendering directly.
So now it's split. A mesh holds an array of mesh "views", and each of these views hold the buckets.
A view can define its own texture overrides, and so every view is an additional N render calls.
This is so-so, but I couldn't think of anything else.

And finally, the actual problem I am now totally stuck on - cameras.
I want to be able to define the camera each instance uses.
It looked as if I could just add a matrix as an attribute, but that doesn't allow to change the viewport, which is kind of important.
I cannot for the life of me think of any way that actually works, that allows all of the above. Switching cameras, switching textures, and instanced rendering.

To make matters worse, I also can't think of any nice way to cull instances.

The only real way I can see to really support everything, is to dynamically keep re-creating buffers for each render call, and copying tons of data each frame, both on the CPU side and GPU side.
For example - sort all of the instances per-camera into different JS arrays (culling can be done here), create a typed array for each one, copy all of the instance data from all of the instances into this array, bind it to a buffer, and redo this for every group, for every "view", for every frame.
This is basically OOP rendering, switched to instanced rendering right at the final step, and I doubt it will be any kind of fast...

tl;dr instanced rendering is a hell to actually use. Are there any known proper techniques to use it with different textures/cameras/whatnot?

Comment: so basically the only thing your instances have in common is their geometry data?

Comment: Generally speaking the textures and camera are common too, but I do want to give the option to have varieties. I am ok with this adding some render calls, since anything will be better than the many thousands I can easily get with OOP rendering, but every time I think I finally have the correct idea, I get stuck with something I didn't think about.

Comment: For example, I thought about generating each frame only a small buffer of indices into the buckets, and then select the proper data in the shader based on the index...but forgot I have to use textures for random memory access, which have their own issues.

Comment: It would probably be better to tell us your ultimate goal rather than how you're trying to solve it. Then we can suggest solutions. For example it's not common to have a camera per instance. Why do you need that?

Comment: To be more precise, I want the notion of "scenes", each owning instances. For example, think of a strategy game, where you can see the models in the map, and their portrait in some UI element - need different cameras and viewports for that. So you are correct in that not every instance actually needs a separate camera, I just wasn't sure how to describe it. As to different textures - it's similar: think of two types of units in a game based on the same geometry, but looking differently.

Comment: For another example, think of the 3D axes in a 3D modeling tool. 3 colored rectangles that get rotated with the scene, but are in their own viewport on some corner.

Comment: Sorry but both your examples make no sense at all, in a strategy game you wouldn't draw the same model you're using for the "UI portrait"  in the actual "game viewport", and your 3D modeling gizmo, how many do you need to draw, right only one. It seems like you've just discovered a hammer and now everything looks like a nail to you. Instancing is **not** a silver bullet making everything fast, its purpose is to draw multiple instances of meshes that differ in only a few per instance attributes.

Comment: The more generic your instancing implementation becomes the less efficient it'll end up being.

Comment: What LJ said. You don't need one shader that draws everything all at once. Typical games have 1000 to 5000 draw calls, maybe more and 100s of kinds of shaders.Sure there are ways to optimize but they are on a per feature basis. One set of shaders for drawing terrain, another set for trees (that's a good place for instancing), yet another for grass (maybe another good place for instancing), another set for drawing characters (skinning), special ones for effects like water or mirrors or glows, separate ones for UI, etc..

Comment: I realize that, the issue is that it's both a generic model viewer, and at the same time I added the capability to load game maps from some game, so I end up with having some models (like terrain stuff, trees, etc.) being rendered thousands of times, but at the same time it's a generic model viewer, not that game map's viewer, so I don't want to suddenly hardcode game rendering logic into it.